# alternative of text-justify:newspaper html

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph, which is `text-align:justify`. But due to some words the difference between words increase so much. There was a property `text-justify:newspaper;` which breaks the words to make them relevantly spaced. But it is not supported by any browser except IE. Is there any alternative for this property.

Or what is the best way to justify them.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/usmanghani/BMDc3/)

Comment: hope this link will help you.. https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/justify.html

Comment: @Kiran this link is related to text-justify:newspaper; but it is only supported by IE.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML :**

```
    <div class="pad1" style="width:190px;">
        <h2 class="center">Why are</h2>
        <p style="word-spacing: 2px;">Our work process includes the smooth communication between the client and the  execution team As soon as we receive a project <b>request, it is</b> immediately registered in the system and a project code is assigned to it. </p>
        <div class="wrapper center">
            <a class="button" href="users/About#why"><span><span><font style="margin-top:1px;"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="More" style="width: 51px; height: 20px;"><canvas width="63" height="25" style="width: 63px; height: 25px; top: -3px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>More</cufontext></cufon></font></span></span></a>
        </div>
   </div>
```

I thik u can use only `word-spacing: 2px;` instead of `text-align: justify; text-justify: newspaper;`

Comment: It is supported only in IE. thats the problem. Otherwise I can use it.

Comment: The `word-spacing` property is well supported, but it does not address the problem at all: it unconditionally adds a two pixels between any “words” (sequences of non-whitespace characters separated by whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

The `text-justify: newspaper` setting does not break words; instead, it adds spacing between letters of a word when justification is needed. Browsers that do not support it (all but IE) do not provide any way to affect the justification process: justification causes spacing between words to be added, and that’s it.

However, you can usually get much better justified text if you make browsers hyphenate words. This reduces the need for added spacing. There are several ways to do hyphenation, but nowadays the approach that works most widely is JavaScript-based hyphenation client-side, using e.g. [Hyphenator.js](https://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/).

Comment: Is there not any other css method to do it. As I don't want to use Hyphenator.js for just single paragraph on my website.

Comment: You can use the `hyphens` property, but browser support is still limited (and depends on the language of the content). For a single paragraph, consider hyphenating it by hand, by adding `&shy;` at permissible hyphenation points.

Comment: Yes till now I am hyphenate it manually. I was just asking if there will be some big text. Then it can be the problem. then at that time using hyphenator is not a big deal

Answer (score -1):

In your case, the best way would be to keep `text-align:left;` by applying a fixed width (either in percentage or pixels) to achieve what you are looking for.

**For Instance,**

```
element.style {
    text-align: left;
    width: 220px;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BMDc3/1/)**

Hope this helps.

***PS:*** width: 220px; is an illustrative value. You can change it as per your scenario.

Comment: But it is looking messed up. I want to justify but don't want space between the words as in the previous fiddle.

Comment: so you can keep `text-align: justify;` and then manage the width. - @عثمانغني

Comment: I want some better solution.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of what you are looking for ?? - @عثمانغني